# jQuery click handler for tr except for an element within a td

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, html-table

I've attached a click handler to the table row element and I Need some help in excluding the element with the class **sub-menu** from the click handler.

I tried the jQuery **:not** selector to exclude an entire **td** element successfully, but that is not what I want.

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/44494oqo/)

Below code Requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/) to work. Please refer the JsFiddle link above.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>Name 1
            <div class="pull-right sub-menu">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>

                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>New User</td>
        <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('table tr').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  });
});
```

** -- Edit -- **

Updated the JsFiddle. I've added the comment below incorporating the answer.

```
// The below "if" condition is the ANSWER.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to see whether the clicked target is inside an element with class `sub-menu`

```js
$(function() {
  $('table tr').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.sub-menu').length) {
      //do your stuff
      alert('Clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>Name 1
        <div class="pull-right sub-menu">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle edit-asset" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border: none;">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>New User</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks, was not aware of the "e.target()" code. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation to stop the click from propagating to the tr:

```
$('.sub-menu').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Tried this, the dropdown menu does not open. The click handler for the button is disabled I think.